# Spivak's Limit Comparison Test proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

On page 476 in Spivak's Calculus he leaves a detail in his Limit Comparison Test proof to the reader and I was just curious as to whether or not I'm showing it correctly. With  2 sequences $a_n$, $b_n > 0$ and $\lim_{n ->\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = c$ we have that $a_n \leq 2cb_n$ for $n \geq N$. To conclude this, I let $\epsilon = c$ then there is an $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$ we have $|\frac{a_n}{b_n} - c| < c$ which is true iff

\begin{align}
|b_n|\cdot |\frac{a_n}{b_n} - c| < c \cdot |b_n| & \iff  |a_n - b_nc| < b_nc \\
& \iff |a_n - b_nc| + |b_nc| < b_nc + |b_nc| = 2b_nc 
\end{align}

This gives us $a_n = |a_n| = |a_n -b_nc + b_nc| \leq |a_n -b_nc| + |b_nc| < 2b_nc$ which is the desired statement.

Is this correct or I'm going about it wrong? Thanks!

Comment: It might be easier to interpret $|a_n/b_n-c| < c$ as meaning the distance from $a_n/b_n$ to $c$ is less  than $c$ itself. It immediately follows that $a_n/b_n$ is less than $c+c = 2c.$

Comment: Yeah it's much easier when you look at it that way, thanks! Is my proof correct otherwise?

Comment: OK but now you need to show the other inequality: $b_{n}<Ma_{n}$ for some fixed $M$ and $n>N$

Comment: Where are you getting that inequality from? Is that for the converse of the statement of the theorem?

Answer (score 1):

If $$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}=c>0$$ then there is an $N\in \mathbb N$ such that $$n\geq N\Rightarrow \frac{c}{2}<\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}<\frac{3c}{2}$$ Then $$\frac{cb_{n}}{2}<a_{n}<\frac{3cb_{n}}{2}$$ and now the desired result can be read off the inequalities.